# Crypto-Js library's hmac-256 script returning function structure instead of value within Google Apps Script, working fine outside?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptojs, hmacsha1

I am setting up a google spreadsheet project to connect to my CryptoExchange
API.
But when it comes to this simple CryptoJs Hmac-sha256 script, it's not working: it is returning the function structure instead of the value, while outside it's working fine ([see my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/9n5oLwxv/54/)).

Now, I understand [from this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731438/inject-external-javascript-file-in-google-app-scriptgoogle-docs#answer-26734725) by Cameron Roberts that Apps Script behaves differently under certain POVs, but I can't understand how this relates.

Besides, **if I just switch script** and use the Stanford Javascript Crypto 
Library, **the code executes perfectly** with no issue at all, both within Google 
Apps Script AND outside of it of course.

Here is my code:

```js
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js').getContentText());


function write() {
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret");
return hash;
}
Logger.log(write());
```

and the console log from Google Apps Script

```js
[19-06-07 00:53:32:859 PDT] {mixIn=
function (a) {
    for (var c in a) {
        a.hasOwnProperty(c) && (this[c] = a[c]);
    }
    a.hasOwnProperty("toString") && (this.toString = a.toString);
}
, extend=
function (a) {
    q.prototype = this;
    var c = new q();
    a && c.mixIn(a);
    c.hasOwnProperty("init") || (c.init = function () {
        c.$super.init.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    c.init.prototype = c;
    c.$super = this;
    return c;
}
, init=
function (a, c) {
    a = this.words = a || [];
    this.sigBytes = c != s ? c : 4 * a.length;
}
, random=
function (a) {
    for (var c = [], d = 0; d < a; d += 4) {
        c.push(4294967296 * h.random() | 0);
    }
    return new r.init(c, a);
}
, words=[-1.956689808E9, 6.97680217E8, -1.940439631E9, -5.01717335E8, -

1.205480281E9, -1.798215209E9, 1.0131952E8, 1.469462027E9], clone=
function () {
    var a = m.clone.call(this);
    a.words = this.words.slice(0);
    return a;
}
, sigBytes=32.0, create=
function () {
    var a = this.extend();
    a.init.apply(a, arguments);
    return a;
}
, toString=
function (a) {
    return (a || k).stringify(this);
}
, concat=
function (a) {
    var c = this.words, d = a.words, b = this.sigBytes;
    a = a.sigBytes;
    this.clamp();
    if (b % 4) {
        for (var e = 0; e < a; e++) {
            c[b + e >>> 2] |= (d[e >>> 2] >>> 24 - 8 * (e % 4) & 255) << 24 - 

8 * ((b + e) % 4);
        }
    } else {
        if (65535 < d.length) {
            for (e = 0; e < a; e += 4) {
                c[b + e >>> 2] = d[e >>> 2];
            }
        } else {
            c.push.apply(c, d);
        }
    }
    this.sigBytes += a;
    return this;
}
, clamp=
function () {
    var a = this.words, c = this.sigBytes;
    a[c >>> 2] &= 4294967295 << 32 - 8 * (c % 4);
    a.length = h.ceil(c / 4);
}
, $super={extend=
function (a) {
    q.prototype = this;
    var c = new q();
    a && c.mixIn(a);
    c.hasOwnProperty("init") || (c.init = function () {
        c.$super.init.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    c.init.prototype = c;
    c.$super = this;
    return c;
}
, mixIn=
function (a) {
    for (var c in a) {
        a.hasOwnProperty(c) && (this[c] = a[c]);
    }
    a.hasOwnProperty("toString") && (this.toString = a.toString);
}
, init=
function () {
}
, clone=
function () {
    return this.init.prototype.extend(this);
}
, create=
function () {
    var a = this.extend();
    a.init.apply(a, arguments);
    return a;
}
}}
```

While the same code [within jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/John_Galassi/9n5oLwxv/54/) works fine

EDIT:
While my question is still a source of curiosity for me, I have just found a whole branch of replies here on stack which involve a specific method **within Google Apps Script** I didn't know about: **a built in Class Utility** for creating HMAC Sha256 signature.

This may not be the very answer to my question in terms of theoretical knowledge, but will probably solve my problem from a practical point of view; so I will look into that now.
Thanks

[Generate a keyed hash value using the HMAC method with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889270/generate-a-keyed-hash-value-using-the-hmac-method-with-google-apps-script?rq=1)

[How to get Hex value from computeHmacSha256Signature method of Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232615/how-to-get-hex-value-from-computehmacsha256signature-method-of-google-apps-scrip)

[get back a string representation from computeDigest(algorithm, value) byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216868/get-back-a-string-representation-from-computedigestalgorithm-value-byte)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647410/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of `8b5f48702995c1598c573db1e21866a9b825d4a794d169d7060a03605796360b` from `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret")` using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about directly calculating the value using the methods of Google Apps Script? In this case, CryptoJS is not used. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
var res = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature("message", "secret")
  .map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Result:

```
8b5f48702995c1598c573db1e21866a9b825d4a794d169d7060a03605796360b
```

#### Note:

The important point for above script is as follows.

- At Google Apps Script, the data which was encrypted by `Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature()` is the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal.
- In your case, the bytes array is converted to the unsigned hexadecimal.

#### References:

- [computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue-key_4)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks very much @Tanaike, this seems the right path! Please let me reserve some time to test it thoroughly, understand it fully and possibly ask some clarifications. I can already tell you however that you have just pointed out a crucial  point (and that is the conversion from bytes array into string) which was already giving me some troubles. Thanks and, see you later!

Comment: @John Galassi Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for it. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: this answer given by @Tanaike was very helpful, synthetic and got the quality of highlighting the crucial point of it all, i.e. the necessity of conversion from array to string. Unfortunately my script still does not work, but thats due to other kind of reasons and has to do with other parts of the code. So thanks very much!

Comment: @John Galassi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.